# JQuery reset the value when the user reselects another value from the dropdown

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have 2 input fields (dropdowns) and I need the user to choose a value from each dropdown in order for the data to be processed.

My jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
   $("#firstDropdown").on("change", function () {
       var firstValue = $("#firstDropdown").val();
           $("#secondDropdown").on("change", function () {
                var secondValue = $("#secondDropdown").val();

                //some code that sends firstValue and secondValue to a class to be processed
           });
           alert(secondValue);
           return;
    });
    alert(firstValue);
    return;
});
```

On the first try when the user chooses for the first time the values from the dropdowns it works fine.

The problem appears if the user decides to reselect another value from the first dropdown (#firstDropdown). Then the value of firstValue is not changed, it remains the first one selected (with debug in the class that receives this data). This is because the code that sends the data to the backend class is located in the function that is related with the change of the second dropdown.

Is there any way to reset the reselected value of the first dropdown?

Comment: Never nest your event handlers.  Put both `.on("change"` event handlers in the doc.ready.  You only need one event handler `$("#firstDropdown,#secondDropwon").on("change...` then check inside the handler if both have a value before sending your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
$("#firstDropdown").on("change", function () {
   var firstValue = $("#firstDropdown").val();
   $("#secondDropdown").on("change", function () {
```

means the second event handler will only fire once the first `select` changes for the first time.   So your users *must* change `first` then `second`.   In addition, if your user changes first more than once, then you will get more than one event handler on the second, potentially creating duplicate records.

This is likely the cause of your "*Then the value of firstValue is not changed*" where changing the second for a 2nd time will fire with the firstValue as it was first, then a second time with the 1st value as it is now - but you're probably doing something (not in the code provided) to stop the 2nd call so not seeing it.

You *could* get around this issue with `$("#secondDropdown").off("change").on("change"...` to ensure only one handler, but it's a bit of a hack!

Instead, define your event handlers up-front, then check inside them if they're good to go.

You can apply a single event handler to multiple elements using a `,` in the selector:

```
$("#firstDropdown, #secondDropdown").on("change",
```

then, within the event handler, check that both values have a value

```
var firstValue = $("#firstDropdown").val();
var secondValue = $("#secondDropdown").val();
if (firstValue !== "" && secondValue !== "") 
  //some code that sends firstValue and secondValue to a class to be processed
```

this *assumes* (not provided in the question) that there is a default option with a blank value, such as:

```
<select id="firstDropdown">
   <option value="">Please select</option>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and the explanations provided are very useful

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(()=>{
        $("#firstDropdown, #secondDropdown").on("change", function () {
            //this.firstValue = $('#firstDropdown :selected').text();               
            var firstValue = $('#firstDropdown').val();              
            vat secondValue = $('#secondDropdown :selected').text();
                
            console.log('firstValue' + firstValue);
            console.log('secondValue' + secondValue);               
        });
    });
```

You have some example here